# Illegal value for GraphQLBigDecimal

Tags: mysql, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I have written a mysql query below:

```
select * from (select a.country country_name,a.country_logo,
count(driver_id) total_empl
,(select count(*) from job where primary_location=a.country) open_jobs
,(select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (nationality='Omani' or nationality is null )) total_omani_in_oman
,round(((select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (nationality='Omani' or nationality is null ))/count(driver_id))*100,2) omani_percentage
,(select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (nationality!='Omani')) total_expat_in_oman
,round(((select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (nationality!='Omani'))/count(driver_id))*100,2) expat_percentage
,(select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (gender in ('Male','M')or gender is null) and (nationality='Omani' or nationality is null )) total_male_emp_in_oman
,(select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (gender in ('FeMale','F')) and (nationality='Omani' or nationality is null ))total_female_emp_in_oman
,(select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (gender in ('Male','M') or gender is null) and nationality!='Omani' ) total_male_expat_in_oman
,(select count(*) from catalog_driver where ifnull(country,'')=a.country and  (gender in ('FeMale','F')) and nationality!='Omani' ) total_female_expat_in_oman
 from 
(select cd.driver_id,cd.nationality,cd.gender,ifnull(cd.country,'')country,ccr.country_logo
from catalog_driver cd
left join catalog_country ccr on ccr.country_name=cd.country) a
group by a.country)aa where 1= 1
```

This query calculates total counts for the employees, open jobs etc grouped by country wise.

But, I am using Graphql at the frontend. I have defined it as `countryLevelHistory` in Schema Definition Language (SDL). I am getting countryLevelHistory in the graphql UI. When I run it, it gives me below error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    "Illegal value for GraphQLBigDecimal:7"
  ],
  "stackTrace": "graphql.GraphQLException: Illegal value for GraphQLBigDecimal:7\r\n\tat com.fuseim.graphql.type.Scalars$2.serialize(Scalars.java:88)\r\n\tat graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.completeValueForScalar(ExecutionStrategy.java:154)\r\n\tat 
...........
...........
...........
}
```

I have google it but got no good results. Anyone having any idea, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using a GraphQLBigDecimal which is a java.math.bigdecimal. This type should have a precision (ie. 7.1).

You may want to use an Int type instead as you're dealing with job counts (no need for precision).